# Memory allocation in 64 bit machine

Tags: c, gcc, 64-bit, callstack

I'd like to ask about memory allocation in 64-bit ubuntu Linux.

I have the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer_one[8], buffer_two[8];

    printf("Size of char: %u\n", sizeof(char));

    printf("Buffer_two is at %p\n", buffer_two);
    printf("Buffer_one is at %p\n", buffer_one);
}
```

and when it is run, the following result shows up

```
$ ./sizeofchar 
Size of char: 1
Buffer_two is at 0x7fff98069910
Buffer_one is at 0x7fff98069900
```

My question is that even with size of char type is 1 byte and I assume (please correct me if I'm wrong here) `Buffer_two` and `Buffer_one` are allocated next to each other, why does the `Buffer_two` and `Buffer_one` memory address are allocated 16 bytes apart.

Comment: This is strictly an implementation detail.An compiler is free to allocate a local variable at whatever address it chooses,Your program should not rely on this address being anything specific.

Comment: Id be willing to bet it is an optimization for 16 byte alignment

Comment: @Als Thanks, I'm not trying to rely on this address. I'm just curious if there is particular reason for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is compiler-dependent behavior. Since these are stack-allocated buffers (which really has nothing to do with memory allocation,) it is up to the compiler how the stack local variables are laid out in the stack.  You could play with this, but I would guess that all arrays are allocated on the stack in 16-byte increments, for one reason or another.

If you look at the disassembly, you could see where in the stack frame the variables are set to be. I have a hunch that a `char[2]` and `char[15]` both end up taking 16 bytes in the stack frame.  Why, I'm not exactly sure. But what I can add, is that the [x64 ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions) specifies that the stack is always 16-byte aligned, and this type of allocation will make it easy to guarantee that.

Comment: The stack pointer should be aligned on 16 bytes before any `call` instruction. I don't know why GCC also aligns stack arrays. It could be that some libc functions are SSE-optimised and require data that is aligned on 16-byte boundary but if those arrays are made global or static GCC no longer aligns them. Also Intel's `icc` places those arrays without gap. Go figure.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart Yes, you're right about `char[2]` and `char[15]`, both are taking 16 bytes in the stack frame. However I also realize for global variables, they are allocated next to each other. Meaning global variables of `char[2]` and `char[15]` are allocated 2 and 15 bytes respectively. Any idea why?

Comment: Well global variables are not allocated on the stack; they are part of the program image when it is loaded into memory. Since there is no stack frame (and hence frame alignment) to worry about, the linker can place them wherever it wants.